# Android - ViewPager fitsSystemWindows (fullscreen) not working

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-fullscreen

I have a ViewPager in my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/main_content"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I want all Fragments to be in fullscreen mode (the screen should be also under status bar). I also set in that Activity:

```
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE |
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
    );
```

and tried several thinks but nothing work. In a different Activity this code works OK.

Do you know where the problem is?

Look at the screenshot. It's still below the Status bar:
[image]

Comment: do you have a solution on this? I got the same issue

Answer (score 0):

For Fullscreen of Activity use fullscreen theme from manifest for that particular activity

```
<activity
   android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
 .../>
```

or you can also apply theme programmatically using `Activity.setTheme()`

If you want to include your app content as a background of statusbar, it is not possible, yes in newer versions you can customize the color of statusbar background.

Answer (score 0):

put this in style.xml

```
<style name="Login" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/white</item>
    <item name="drawerArrowStyle">@style/DrawerArrowStyle</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

and this in manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.activities.LoginActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Login"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`. That flag is used when you want to keep some components from displaying over the status and navigation bars.